# Turns over but Wont start

Tags: dodge, cranks-wont-run

Ok so I'm going down the road the other day an my truck just shuts off I'm headed to get gas but the Lil thing in the ceiling of the truck says 10 or 12 miles to empty so I think it's lieing I send an get a gallon or so more gas just to make sure an it turns over won't start so I pull it home first I put my code reader on it it shows an engine code for the egr position sensor (which i changed an didnt make a difference) then i check all the fuses an check value on the fuel rail which is getting fuel then I replaced both cam an crankshaft position sensors neither of which made a difference it has also started to drain the battery if left connect over night the battery I've also replaced

Comment: Are you getting a spark at all of the spark plugs?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/model/engine of your Dodge truck?